# Eclipse RCP editor - Add Text when enter is pressed

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have text editor created using eclipse RCP. I have registered the editor with ITextListener.
Requirement: When enter is pressed by user, add six digit number on the new line generated because of enter.

I have captured the enter key event in the listener.
I have my six digit number ready.
I just want to add that number to the new line being generated.

Please find below my code
    private class VPTextListener implements ITextListener{

```
    @Override
    public void textChanged(TextEvent event) {

        if(null!=event && null!=event.getDocumentEvent()){

            String text = event.getDocumentEvent().fText;
            if(text.equals(AGConstants.LINE_SEPARATOR)){
                int offset = event.getDocumentEvent().fOffset;
                try {
                    int offsetLine = event.getDocumentEvent().fDocument.getLineOfOffset(offset);
                    int lineLength = event.getDocumentEvent().fDocument.getLineLength(offsetLine);
                    int offsetOfLine = event.getDocumentEvent().fDocument.getLineOffset(offsetLine);
                    String line = event.getDocumentEvent().fDocument.get(offsetOfLine, lineLength);
                    if(!ModelUtil.isEmpty(line) && line.length()>=6){
                        String seqNum = line.substring(0, 6);
                        int iSeqNum = ModelUtil.makeNullZero(seqNum);
                        if(0==iSeqNum){
                            return;
                        }
                        String newSeqNum = ModelUtil.make6(iSeqNum+1);

                        event.getDocumentEvent().fDocument.replace(offset+2, newSeqNum.length(), newSeqNum);
                    }
                } catch (BadLocationException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But after execution it gives BadLocationException.

Please help me on this. 
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Is 'offset + 2' a valid position in the document? If you want to insert text rather than replace existing text the second parameter to `replace` should be 0.

Comment: Actually I want to insert text when enter is pressed by the user. event.getDocumentEvent().fDocument.replace(offset, 0, text)... It is inserting text but later behaviour is strange. After pressing arrow keys text is changing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [IAutoEditStrategy](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjface%2Ftext%2FIAutoEditStrategy.html). It would roughly look like this:

```
public class NewLineAutoEditStrategy implements IAutoEditStrategy {

    public void customizeDocumentCommand(IDocument document, DocumentCommand command) {
        if (command.length == 0 && command.text != null) {
            // is not a replace

            if (TextUtilities.equals(document.getLegalLineDelimiters(), command.text) != -1) {
                // text being insterted is a legal line delimiter

                command.text += getMagicNumber();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

You might also check the caret position (if at the end of line) or if the user hit Shift along with the Return button. In such cases you might want to disable command customization.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It is working for me. I have created class as mentioned by you. Then I have registered it in SourceViewerConfiguration of my editor. :-)